# Fermat vs Mersenne as modulus

Tags: algorithm, modulus

So there are some number theory applications where we need to do modulo with big numbers, and we can choose the modulus. There's two groups that can get huge optimizations - Fermat and Mersenne.

So let's call an N bit sequence a chunk. N is often not a multiple of the word size.

For Fermat, we have M=2^N+1, so 2^N=-1 mod M, so we take the chunks of the dividend and alternate adding and subtracting.

For Mersenne, we have M=2^N-1, so 2^N=1 mod M, so we sum the chunks of the dividend.

In either case, we will likely end up with a number that takes up 2 chunks. We can apply this algorithm again if needed and finally do a general modulo algorithm.

Fermat will make the result smaller on average due to the alternating addition and subtraction. A negative result isn't that computationally expensive, you just keep track of the sign and fix it in the final modulo step. But I'd think bignum subtraction is a little slower than bignum addition.

Mersenne sums all chunks, so the result is a little larger, but that can be fixed with a second iteration of the algorithm at next to no extra cost.

So in the end, which is faster?

---

[Schönhage–Strassen uses Fermat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhage%E2%80%93Strassen_algorithm#Choice_of_ring) There might be some other factors other than performance that make Fermat better than Mersenne - or maybe it's just straight up faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a prime modulus, you're going to make the decision based on the convenience of the size.

For example, **2^31-1** is often convenient on 64-bit architectures, since it fits pretty snugly into 32 bits and and the product of two of them fits into a 64-bit word, either signed or unsigned.

On 32-bit architectures, **2^16+1** has similar advantages.  It doesn't quite fit unto 16 bits, of course, but if you treat 0s a special case, then it's still pretty easy to multiply them in a 32-bit word.